# How to prevent Liferay modify my web.xml?

Tags: java, spring, liferay, liferay-6

I am migrating a Liferay 5.x site to 6.1GA2. My problem is that Liferay 6.1 modifies the `web.xml` of a deployed app that is basically a web service implementation.

It changes the `<listeners>` definitions which is problematic because there are some Spring-magic involved and the `ContextLoaderListener` is not initialized correctly.

**Is there any way to convince Liferay to leave my `web.xml` untouched?** I have already debugged the `BaseDeployer.updateWebXml()` method that does the magic but as I see there is no option to do that. I found a few bug tickets in the ticketing system with similar issues but it seems the [latest patched version](https://github.com/vpugar/liferay-portal/blob/6.1.x_LPS-29103/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/tools/deploy/BaseDeployer.java) of the file still does not support this feature.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The changes in web.xml are required for webapps that Liferay is interacting with. It appears when you deploy your webapplication through Liferay's `${liferay.home}/deploy` folder. If you have a webapp that's unrelated to Liferay and does not need this, you can just deploy it directly to your appserver, without going through Liferay's deploy folder.

Comment: Oh man, If I recognize that it that would have saved me some time :D I ended up by patching the `BaseDeployer` class in `portal-impl` with a custom property that does not run the `secureWebXml()` method (this is the one that messes up the ordering of `<listener>`).